# Redux state is filled correctly, but the component doesn't display the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have this component (associated with the route `/product/:id` in App.js)

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

import Spinner from '../components/Spinner';
import { getProductDetails } from '../actions/productActions';

const ProductDetailsScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const { product, loading, error } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.productDetails
  );

  console.log(product);// < ------- This outputs the previously display product, then undefined, then the targeted product
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getProductDetails(match.params.id));
  }, [match]);


  

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='container'>
        {loading ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : error ? (
          <h1>{error}</h1>
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h1>{product.name}</h1>
            <span>
              <strong>Price: </strong>${product.price}
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    <div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetailsScreen;
```

In another component I have this

```
 <Link to={`/product/${_id}`}>View Details</Link>
```

which is supposed to go to ProductDetailsScreen component, and fill the screen with the product's details based on the `_id` passed. However, although the redux state is populated correctly from the backend with the product's details whose `_id` is passed, the components' elements aren't filled with the product's details as it is supposed to be, although I am checking if the product is done loading and there is no error. The component seems to be rendered 3 times based on the `console.log(product)`. The first time it outputs the previously displayed product (I think I need to clear the state), then undefined, and then the target product!

Why? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT1:

the reducer

```
export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { product: {} }, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case PRODUCT_GET_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case PRODUCT_GET_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, success: true, product: payload };
    case PRODUCT_GET_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: payload,
      };
    case PRODUCT_GET_RESET:
      return { product: {} };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and the action

```
export const getProductDetails = (productId) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_GET_REQUEST,
    });

    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${productId}`);

    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_GET_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_GET_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: can you see at least layout? I mean `<div className='product-details'>`

Comment: Yes, I see the layout, but not filled.

Comment: What do you see for `<h1 className='product-name'>{product.name}</h1>`? Do you see `undefiend` string or nothing?

Comment: Just the CSS layout, and the hard coded labels in the html elements. Anything product-related is not rendered!

Comment: can you check `loading` by logging the value?

Comment: Sine the component is rendered 3 times, I got false, true, false for the `loading` part of the state.

Comment: That's weird. Can you upload your code to codesandbox?

Comment: Which parts? I have a backend and a number of interconnected components.

Comment: It would be helpful If you can upload runnable project so that I can debug on my side.

Comment: Can you try console logging your state correctly, i.e. ***not*** in the function body of the component? Try a `useEffect` specifically to log `product` when the component renders and report back. Please also include the action and reducer code so that we may trace the flow of logic and data.

Comment: @DrewReese I did this `useEffect(() => console.log(loading, product) , [])` and the result is `false` for `loading` and the previously viewed product (not the current one) for `product`

Comment: Yeah, but you missed adding `product` and `loading` as dependencies to see how they update each render cycle. I suspect it is rendering the data saved in state from the last time the page was loaded, and then you get the new data. If you wipe app state/persisted app state do you still see the "previous" state?

Comment: That's true, but neither the old nor the new data are displayed in the component. Why?

Comment: Is `loading` ever `false` and `error` falsey to get to the UI you want rendered? When you log `product` do you see the data you want rendered? Can you update your question to add the other action/reducer code requested? If `loading` is `false` and `error` is falsey, and `product` is an object with defined properties then I see no reason why nothing would be rendered but the labels.

Comment: please recheck if old `product` and new `product` is different. If it isn't different, please upload your `reducer`

Comment: @DrewReese `product` has the product data I want in the 3rd render when I log it in the component's body. I updated the question by including the reducer and the action.

Comment: @baymax I updated the question and included the reducer.

Comment: @baymax `product` is different with renders when I log it in the component's body. In the 1st render, the old product is logged, then `undefined`, and then the new product!!

Comment: Looks like the `PRODUCT_GET_SUCCESS` creates a new `product` object, but all your reducer cases neglect to shallow copy the state object. `PRODUCT_GET_REQUEST` wipes out the `product` state, which is why you see `undefined`.

Comment: @DrewReese I copied the state as you and baymax suggested, but nothing has changed, except the component doesn't re-render as per the console.log expression in the component's body. In Redux dev tools the state is populated correctly, though!

Comment: Yeah at this point I think a live codesandbox that reproduces the issue would be beneficial. As I said, if you are getting the correct redux state in the component then I see no reason it wouldn't update the DOM.

Comment: OK, I will try to put together a minimum runnable code on codesandbox.

Comment: Stupid me, the data returned from the backend is an array, so I have to update the action accordingly ```dispatch({
      type: PRODUCT_GET_SUCCESS,
      payload: data[0],
    });``` or update the fetching from `Model.find({_id: req.params.id})` to `Model.findById(req.params.id)` and keep the action as is. Thanks for your interactions Drew and baymax.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below.

**Reducer**

```js
export const productDetailsReducer = (state = { product: {} }, action) => {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case PRODUCT_GET_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case PRODUCT_GET_SUCCESS:
      return { ...state, loading: false, success: true, product: payload };
    case PRODUCT_GET_FAIL:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: payload
      };
    case PRODUCT_GET_RESET:
      return { ...state, product: {} };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I did that, but nothing changed. I only care for product when successfully loaded.  That's why I don't think I need to spread the state for each action type.